# Using UserDefault custom suite for namespacing keys

Tags: ios, swift, foundation, userdefaults

I know the typical use case for using a custom suite for the UserDefaults in iOS (not macos) is to share data to app Extensions.

I am wondering if it does make sense using a custom suite like

```
class UserData {

    private var source = UserDefaults(suiteName: "MyApp.userData")!

    ...
}
```

to better isolate (or slightly better "namespace") the key-values related to a module of the app from another. In the simple example i would like to store some user related data (not worth being inserted in the regular DB) and wipe them out for example on user logout.

Using the `standard` UserDefaults would require me to prepend a prefix to the keys, or wrap all the calls, or similar approaches, but it seams to me that using a suite is just more suited (pun unintended), as i could directly deleted it or iterate over it (for reasons) without fear of touching other keys or worst overwrite existing ones (keys conflict).

**TLDR:** is it fine to use a more than a suite for persistence of small data in place of a monolitic UserDefault? Which cons could be facing, i have not found a single article (not involving extensions data sharing) and as usual Apple documentation is all but clear, if not misleading.

**Bonus:**
Initilly i though this would also rule out all those system injected keys, but it appear after a test that they are as well copied in the suite instance of the UserDefaults despite i haven´t "added" the suite as a child of the `standard` one, do you have an explanation for this?

Comment: @matt Maybe i expressed myself wrongly, i meant i want to store RELEVANT data in the DB (coredata, realm, backend,..) and NON-RELEVANT data (eg: scroll position of a table view for restoration of UI) to the userdefaults. And non relevant data can be user related (just an example).

Comment: Scroll position should exactly go in User Defaults. No need for a suite.

Comment: I understand, and that is the current state, but i have A LOT of user defaults, and i was wondering if there was an elegant way to kind of “namespace” them for easier handling. Suite are just instances of UserDfaults for what i understood and they seem a good fit for my needs

Comment: Maybe ordinary files would be a better fit for some things?